# How to disable drag side menu in ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am using two side menu in my ionic app i.e. on left and right side.

How can I disable dragging right menu only. I tried using `$ionicSideMenuDelegate.canDragContent(false)` but it disables both side dragging.

**HTML for ref**

```
<ion-nav-bar>

<ion-nav-buttons side="left">
<button menu-toggle="left">
</button>
</ion-nav-buttons>

<ion-nav-buttons side="right">
<button menu-toggle="right">
</button>
</ion-nav-buttons>

</ion-nav-bar>
```

Comment: Try `this.menuController.swipeEnable(false);`

Answer (score 3):

> How can I disable dragging right menu only.

**IMPORTANT: The following answer works only in Ionic2/3**.

You can use the **[swipeEnable(shouldEnable, menuId)](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/app/MenuController/#swipeEnable)** method, but only in the right menu. Since you have only one menu on each side, instead of the id, we can use the side (`'left'` or `'right'`).

```
import { MenuController, ... } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
    templateUrl: 'app.html'
})
export class MyApp {

  constructor(private menuCtrl: MenuController, ...) {
    this.menuCtrl.swipeEnable(false, 'right');

    // ...

  }

  // ...

}
```

Comment: Could you please mention a solution for ionic v1? I am not familiar with ionic2 or above . Tags for ionic2 and ionic3 were edited..not by me

Comment: I'm sorry about the tags, it was my mistake. I'm afraid I'm not familiar with Ionic v1 :(